# Link a Webapp to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some help/advice. I have a simple Webapp for teachers at my school that lets them quickly record points for groups on their device. The interface looks something like this:

[image]

The data is sent to a Google Sheet where they can compile/analyze the results over time.

Currently, this is used by one person so it is only linked to one Google Sheet. I created the interface in GAS, then built a database in Sheets, then linked the web app and the Sheet from within the GAS script, like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxx"); //ID for the Sheet is entered here.
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Setup");

  var col = ws.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var hlr = getLastRowSpecial(col);

  var col = ws.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var alr = getLastRowSpecial(col);

  var groups = ws.getRange("A2:A"+hlr).getValues().flat();

  htmlOutput.groups = groups;

  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('Points');
}
```

After manually creating and linking the two, I used GAS to "Deploy" the script as a web app and shared the link with the teacher who is using it.

For my next step, I'd like to make this available to other teachers. But, I'm not sure how to go about making this available without having to manually create the Sheet, copy the ID into the GAS, and then deploy and share the link.

Can anyone give advice on how to make this web app easier to customize and share? One idea is that I can create a Google Sheet as a template and then use it as a container for the script. Then, add a button or drop-down that, once the teacher completes the necessary fields in the template, they can click the button or drop down to create the link to deploy the web app. BUT, I don't know if it is possible to publish a web app through GAS without doing so manually.

**EDIT**
To clarify my issue, I need this web app to be tied to a different Sheet for every instance that is created. I'd like to publish this as an add-on, but I need all the responses to go to individual Sheets owned and controlled by the user.

**EDIT #2**
I have published the app as a Sheets add-on. I tried using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` to create a link to the web app side of things, but (as reported in other posts) that doesn't work.
What I need is a single web app that each user can tie to a unique Google Sheet.
Is there a way to put the Sheet ID in the web app URL and have the web app pull the ID from the URL? If I could do that, I can handle the rest.
For example, if my web app link is: https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCDE/exec
and my Sheet ID is: 12345678
Can I make it so the link https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCDE/exec/12345678 will pass the 12345678 into the script?
Or a similar method?
Any ideas or resources are appreciated.

Comment: Publishing a Add on is one way.

Comment: In the case of `For my next step, I'd like to make this available to other teachers.`, where is the Spreadsheet? Namely, who is the owner of Spreadsheet?

Comment: @TheMaster, that's the eventual plan, but would it need to be published as a Sheets add on our as a web app?

Comment: I think so. Once published, I think you'll have a single web app with multiple users.

Comment: Publishing the add-on is one approach to share and distribute your web app. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview) you can read the basics. Additionally, who is the owner of the main Sheet? As in, is there one Sheet per teacher? Or is there one single main Sheet?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, there would be a different sheet for each person, but multiple people might share a sheet.
I think this is a very important clarification that I missed. I will explain further in an edit on the OP.

Comment: @TeedFerguson Thank you for making the question more clear. I now understand that you want to publish the add-on. What is preventing you from doing it? Could you please explain where you find difficulties in the publishing process?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, I guess its largely just ignorance about the process. I have published Google editor add-ons before, but never one that uses a web app as part of the interface. Currently, I manually get the web app link from the script page. I'm just unsure of how, if I publish the add-on, the user will launch the web app interface. I may just have to [attempt to] publish it so I can see what it looks like.

Comment: @TeedFerguson A web app is a good approach if you need an interface like the one described. After [deploying a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) you will get a link that can be shared with the users, that is one way for them to open the web app.
Also please be aware that you can [test deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment) before releasing them. If you find difficulties in one step of the deployment/test, please tell me where to help you more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I used e param to pass the Sheet URL to the webapp.

Comment: can you expand a bit on this answer?