# How do I publish get the link to a publish web app in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

This is a continuation of my [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842967/link-a-webapp-to-a-google-sheet?noredirect=1#comment128661597_72842967). In a nutshell, I have a web app that is tied to a Google Sheet. I want to publish it as an add-on for Sheets. The web app is built based on the information inputted on the Sheet:
[image]

Yields:
[image]

I'm having a really hard time framing this question in a way that makes sense, but is there a way to add a link to the web app from Sheets? I want to have something that looks like this so that the drop-down will give a link to the web app:
[image]

Typically, I get the link by deploying the web app from within GAS. But, if I publish the app on Google Cloud Console/Marketplace, how can I get the link to be tied to that drop-down? Is there a "getUrl" for web apps that are contained within a Sheet?

**EDIT:**
I tried using the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`. When I run the "Manage Deployments" I get this screen:
[image]
The URL is correct and takes me to the web app but the link generated by the getUrl() returns something containing the Deployment ID and takes me to a "Page not found error"
[image]

Comment: If the linked duplicate answers doesn't answer your question, [edit] your question to explain how the answers don't satisfy your question. If you're having trouble implementing a solution in the duplicate or don't understand a solution provided, ask a new specific question with the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I added an edit to probe my question a bit further

Comment: Can you explain how is this different for the one marked by @TheMaster?